# Laravel validation rule 'required_with' does not work with Array

Tags: arrays, laravel, validation

I'm trying to validate 3 arrays that must have the same lenght if first is present, because they are correlated.
The input that I'm recieveing is this:

```
'materiales' => 
  array (
    0 => '181',
    1 => '191',
    2 => '189',
  ),
 'cantidades' => 
  array (
    0 => '27.65',
    1 => '1.27',
    2 => '26.24',
  ),
 'unidades' => 
  array (
    0 => '0',
    1 => '1',
  ),
```

With this kind of input I want a validation error because 'unidades'[3] is not present, but the validator is considering the data valid. My rules are:

```
'materiales' => 'required|array',
'materiales.*' => 'nullable|exists:articulos,id',
'cantidades' => 'required|array',
'cantidades.*' => 'required_with:materiales.*|numeric|min:0.0001',
'unidades' => 'required|array',
'unidades.*' => 'required_with:materiales.*|required|numeric',
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you need all the arrays to be of the same length, I would suggest that you validate the length for each array

```
'materiales' => 'required|array',
'materiales.*' => 'nullable|exists:articulos,id|size:3',
'cantidades' => 'required|array',
'cantidades.*' => 'required_with:materiales.*|numeric|min:0.0001|size:3',
'unidades' => 'required|array',
'unidades.*' => 'required_with:materiales.*|required|numeric|size:3',
```

I assumed you need the arrays to be of length 3

Comment: The arrays can be of arbitrary length

Answer (score 0):

What about using the `size` rule instead? I haven't tried this but it should work:

```
'materiales'   => 'required|array',
'materiales.*' => 'nullable|exists:articulos,id',
'cantidades'   => 'required|array',
'cantidades.*' => 'required_with:materiales.*|numeric|min:0.0001',
'unidades'     => 'required|array',
'unidades.*'   => 'required_with:materiales.*|required|numeric|size:' . count(request('materiales')),
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but the error message is a little bit confusing for the user: `unidades.3` must be 3. I'm pretty sure I can solve this using your advice or any other custom rule, but I'm very interested why the `required_with` rule does not work.

Comment: required_with expects that field to exist at all, it won't work for dynamic elements. You can override the message like in the `messages()` method if you use form request, or as a third parameter in the Validator, using this, `'unidades.*.size' => 'Your message here'`.